# Geojson file not showing up in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gis

I am trying to use Mike Bostock's geopaths plugin for D3.js, as seen here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4310087

When I use Mike's raw file the visualization shows up fine, but when I use my own nothing shows up.

Here is my Geojson file, what am I doing wrong?

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5a1ada2ac7d57383b661

Comment: It looks like your GeoJSON file is not correctly encoded. How did you generate it?

Answer (score 0):

Your file looks correct.  I assume that you're referring to the geopaths file within your local directory.  In order to utilize this file when calling `d3.json()` the folder from which you are accessing the file must be served by an http server.

A simple http server can be created by the following node.js module: https://npmjs.org/package/http-server.

Comment: or you can use pythons simple server or xammp or ... see some of the description in this gg [answer](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/d3-js/138255m4xd/stacked-to-grouped-bars#20130803ej2zmnlh2f5co42ovpapvevpy4)